# How to add background image on rendered image on python script

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have a script in which I have a moving camera, the objective is to render multiple views of some objects. Now I want to add a random background image to each rendered image.
I found other threads on the matter, but their solutions do not work with Blender 2.80.
I tried this function:

```
def add_background(filepath):
    img = bpy.data.images.load(filepath)
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            space_data = area.spaces.active
            bg = space_data.background_images.new()
            bg.image = img
            space_data.show_background_images = True
            break

    texture = bpy.data.textures.new("Texture.001", 'IMAGE')
    texture.image = img
    bpy.data.worlds['World'].active_texture = texture
    bpy.context.scene.world.texture_slots[0].use_map_horizon = True
```

But I get `AttributeError: 'SpaceView3D' object has no attribute 'background_images'`. I guess something changed on Blender API.

How could I do that or fix this function?

Comment: Background image do not appear in renders anyway, so you don't need the first part of you algorithm that loops over the areas. Setting the world texture works, if you have a 360°x180° image.  `use_map_horizon` doesn't exist in Blender 2.8, you would want to use an environment texture node and a mapping node instead. However I believe what you want to perform is compositing, which means you would have to switch a texture in the compositing nodes (and possibly also create the node setup).

Comment: Thank for your response. I really have no knowledge of 3D modeling and Blender. Could you provide a code example?